# Working with linked lists. Why my insert function is not working?

Tags: c++

I am trying to insert numbers which are a result of deduction of two neighbors in already made up list.

```
        #include<iostream>

        using namespace std;

        struct Element{
            int x;
            Element* next;
        };

        Element* createList(){
            int i,n;
            Element *head=NULL,*p=NULL;
            cout<<"How many elements: ";
            cin>>n;
            for(i=0;i<n;i++){
                if(i==0) {
                    head=new Element();
                    p=head;
                }
                else{
                    p->next=new Element();
                    p=p->next;
                }
                cout<<"Value: ";
                cin>>p->x;
            }
            p->next=NULL;
            return head;
        }

        void printList(Element* head){
            Element* p=head;
            cout<<"List values: "<<endl;
            while(p!=NULL){
                cout<<p->x<<"   ";
                p=p->next;
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }

        Element* createElement(int x){
            Element* element=new Element();
            element->x=x;
            element->next=NULL;
            return element;
        }


        Element* insert(Element* head){
            Element *p=head,*temp=NULL;
            while(p->next!=NULL){
                temp=createElement(p->next->x - p->x);
                temp->next=p->next;
                p->next=temp;
                p=p->next;
            }
            return head;
        }


        int main(){
            Element* head=NULL;
            head=createList();
            printList(head);
            head=insert(head);
            printList(head);
            return 0;
        }
```

I expected that my updated list will contain these numbers which should be placed between every two numbers in the original list but when my program encounters the insert function it is just running and never finishes.
Example: 
    Original list: 1 5 8 12 30
     Updated list: 1 4 5 3 8 4 12 18 30

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: `head=insert(head);` doesn't make sense at all. What is `createList()`?

Comment: I dont think you have posted the complete code, for instance definition for `createList` is missing. Please add complete code to get help and also I suggest you to do some debugging before posting.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think it is just the name `insert` that is confusing. I suppose OP wants `insert` not to insert some particular element, but " numbers which are a result of deduction of two neighbors in already made up list."

Comment: Drawing boxes and arrows on paper is the best way to debug.

Comment: you know that there is `std::list` ? If this is an assignment then imho you should mention it in the question, becuase typically they come with all sorts of strange requirements

Comment: OT.: All the member assignments you do in `createElement()` should actually be part of the initialization in `Element::Element()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw it (pencil and paper is better than ASCII but is hard to post here):

After `temp->next = p->next`:

```
      head
       |
       v
     +---+     +---+
p -->|  ------>|  -----> ...
     +---+     +---+
                 ^
        +---+    |
temp -->|  ------+
        +---+
```

`p->next=temp;`

```
      head
       |
       v
     +---+     +---+
p -->|  ---+   |  -----> ...
     +---+ |   +---+
           v     ^
        +---+    |
temp -->|  ------+
        +---+
```

`p=p->next;`

```
      head
       |
       v
     +---+     +---+
     |  ---+   |  -----> ...
     +---+ |   +---+
           v     ^
        +---+    |
temp -->|  ------+
        +---+     
          ^
          |
          p
```

... and repeat until you see why `p->next!=NULL` will never become false.